# Which en-route services are available to UK GA pilots?

Tags: general-aviation, uk

I have recently taken up flying again in the UK, and although very little has changed in the 10 years I have been inactive, the one area which seems to have changed is in the en-route services available to pilots.

It used to be the case that you could request a Flight Information Service (FIS) and a Radar advisory (RA) service - I seem to recall there being one other which I never used, which I cannot quite remember the name of.

I believe the FIS is now referred to as a "Basic" service, is this assumption correct? Does it vary in any material way from the defunct FIS?

What other services are available to GA pilots in uncontrolled airspace? Where do I find the details of stations and what service(s) they provide?

Comment: Some information [here](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP%20774Issue2_3.pdf): Services are Basic Service, Traffic Service, Deconfliction Service, Procedural Service. Also [this flyer](http://airspacesafety.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/atsocas_q_start.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @mins - If nobody feels llike writing up a good answer I'll do so from the official sources when I get time. I think this is a useful Q/A to have here at aviation.se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [UK AIP ENR 1.1 "General Rules", chapter 2 "UK Flight Information Services"](http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/pamslight-A5ED1F63B63F8FF9F9D98C29D7457974/7FE5QZZF3FXUS/EN/AIP/ENR/EG_ENR_1_1_en_2016-06-23.pdf) the UK FIRs meet the ICAO requirements with the following Flight Information Services (FIS): Basic Service, Traffic Service, Deconfliction Service and Procedural Service.

This is an extract of the contents of the chapter:

> **Basic Service**
>   Provides advice and information useful for the safe and efficient conduct of flights. This may include weather
>   information, changes of serviceability of facilities, conditions at aerodromes, general airspace activity information, and any other
>   information likely to affect safety. The avoidance of other traffic is solely the pilot's responsibility.
>
> Basic Service is available under IFR outside controlled airspace in any meteorological conditions, or under VFR. A pilot may change
>   heading, route, or level without advising the controller. A controller will not issue specific heading instructions; however, generic
>   navigational assistance may be provided on request.
>
> **Traffic Service**
>   Traffic Service is a surveillance based ATS, where in addition to the provisions of a Basic Service, the controller provides specific
>   surveillance derived traffic information to assist the pilot in avoiding other traffic. The avoidance of other traffic is solely the pilot's
>   responsibility.
>   Traffic Service is available under IFR outside controlled airspace in any meteorological conditions, or under VFR.
>
> **Deconfliction Service**
>   A Deconfliction Service is a surveillance based ATS where, in addition to the provisions of a Basic Service, the controller provides
>   specific surveillance derived traffic information and deconfliction advice.
>   A Deconfliction Service shall only be provided to flights under IFR in Class G Airspace, irrespective of meteorological conditions.[...] A controller will provide traffic information, accompanied with a heading and/or level aimed at achieving a planned deconfliction minima.
>
> **Procedural Service**
>   A Procedural Service is a non surveillance ATS where, in addition to the provisions of a Basic Service, the controller provides
>   instructions, which if complied with, shall achieve deconfliction minima against other aircraft participating in the Procedural
>   Service. Neither traffic information nor deconfliction advice can be passed with respect to unknown traffic. A Procedural Service shall only be provided to flights under IFR, irrespective of meteorological conditions. [...] the pilot remains wholly responsible for terrain clearance at all times. [...] A controller will provide deconfliction instructions by allocating levels, radials, tracks, routes, time restrictions, approach clearances and holding instructions, or use pilot position reports, aimed at achieving a planned deconfliction minima.